# powershell script for check-in documents inside folders and sub folders on SharePoint Document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

We have 50,000+ has been checked out by users. We need to check-in back. Document library contain sub folders inside. Can anyone please powershell script for us.

Example: Document library name "Test lib", under that test1 folder, under that test2 folder, under that test3 folder likewise. on test8 or 9 folder checked-out file exist. We tried below script, no error and nothing coming. Just an seconds its coming completed. Seems something we are missing. Please suggest me.

---

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ea 0 
 
Function CheckInAllDocs([string]$DoclibURL){ 
    if ($docliburl.EndsWith("/")){ 
        $docliburl = $docliburl.Substring(0,$docliburl.length-1) 
    } 
    $web = get-spweb -identity $docliburl.Substring(0,$docliburl.LastIndexOf("/")) 
    $doclib = $web.lists |where {$_.RootFolder.Name -eq $docliburl.Substring($docliburl.LastIndexOf("/")+1,$docliburl.length-$docliburl.LastIndexOf("/")-1)} 


    ForEach($item in $doclib.checkedoutfiles){ 
        #$item.TakeoverCheckout() 
        $doclib.GetItemById($item.ListItemId).file.CheckIn("Checked in by Script") 
        write-host "$($item.LeafName) has been checked in" 
    } 
} 
#To use enter the location of a document library 
CheckInAllDocs "http://server.com/apps/Files"
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to check in all check-out files under a library, you may have a try below cmdlets:

```
   function CheckInDocument([string]$url)
    {
        $spWeb = Get-SPWeb $url
        $getFolder = $spWeb.GetFolder("Test lib")
        $getFolder.Files | Where { $_.CheckOutStatus -ne "None" } | ForEach
        {
            Write-Host "$($_.Name) is Checked out To: $($_.CheckedOutBy)"
            $_.CheckIn("Checked In By Administrator")
            Write-Host "$($_.Name) Checked In" -ForeGroundColor Green
        }
        $spWeb.Dispose()
    }
```

BR